# how to convert unicode to persian text in csv file with excel

Tags: excel, csv, unicode

[image]

The persian text in csv file getting unicode, please anyone help thanks in advance

Comment: You are not getting Unicode, just Latin1. In any case, I think your question is off-topic here: it is not about programming. We have a sister site: Superuser (links on top right icon) which may be more relevant. But what it is the encoding of the original file? It is an important information.

Comment: Use UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding when writing the CSV file, then Excel will read it correctly.